# Open sets in the unitary group $ U(\mathcal{H}) $ of a Hilbert space $ \mathcal{H} $.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional Hilbert space and let $(x_i)_1^\infty$ be an orthonormal basis for $H$.

Consider $U(H)$ the unitary group of the continuous unitary operators on $H$. Equip $U(H)$ with the topology in which the basic neighborhood of the identity I has the form
$$V=B(F,\epsilon)=\{S \in U(H): ||y-S(y)||<\epsilon\mbox{ for all $y$ in $F$}\}$$ where $F$ is a finite subset of the orthonormal basis.

Let $C$ be in $U(H)$. We have that $CV$ is an open neighborhood of $C$. Now, I want to show that:
$$CV=\{S \in U(H): || C(y)-C(S(y))||<\epsilon\mbox{ for all $y$ in $F$}\}.$$ Is this true? How can I prove it?
An inclusion I think is clear, I show that $CV$ is contained in this set. Let $CS$ in $CV$. We have $||C(S(f))-C(f)||=||C(S(f)-f)||<||C||\epsilon=\epsilon$. Is this ok?
thank you

Comment: What is $P$? It is unclear.

Comment: @sinbadh sorry for the misunderstanding, I called P the set that I hope is equal to CV. It's just its name. Is it clear now?

Comment: @user1952009 Sorry but $(C^*T)\in V$ means that $||(C^*T-I)y||<\epsilon$ not that $||C^*(S-I)y||<\epsilon$. So I don't think it works for the inclusion of that set in CV

Comment: yes sorry $CV$ is the set such that $S \in CV \implies \epsilon > ||(C^* S - I)y|| = ||(S - C)y||$. and $||(C-CS)y|| < \epsilon$ doesn't imply that  $||(S - C)y|| < \epsilon$ at all.

Comment: @user1952009 I don't understand what you mean. If $T\in CV$ then $T=CS$ with $S\in V$ by definition of product of sets in a topological groups. From this I can't see what is wrong. It still remains the problem of the other inclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, unitaries preserve the norm. So 
$$
\|Cy-CSy\|=\|C(y-Sy)\|=\|y-Sy\|.
$$
Thus, $CV=V$.